# Defining a 'base' import file in Python

Tags: python, import

I would like to define a base file `base.py` that contains all the appropriate imports and when I import it to my main file with `import base` then its imports are loaded. In other words, let `base.py` contain the following

```
#base.py
import moduleA
import moduleB
import moduleC
#etc
```

and

```
#main.py
import base
```

Then `moduleA,moduleB,moduleC` are loaded to the main file. I have tried doing it this way but it seems incorrect as Python does not return the expected results.

Thanks

EDIT: Found that `from base import *` works pretty fine

Comment: What were the expected results?

Comment: You could also have used `base.moduleA.whatever` in `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should uses `__init__.py` file for this usage. This will set the container folder as python module.

#### Example

You have:

```
myfolder/
|- module1.py
|- module2.py
|- __init__.py
```

In your `__init__.py`:

```
from module1 import foo
from module2 import bar
```

You will be able to do:

```
from myfolder import foo, bar
```